# CSS text in span is overlapping text within another when within a list

Tags: html, css, web

easier to show than explain: 
 
[image]

As you can see on the second option the number is overlapping the first number. Where I want it to expand so that it is not overlapping this second one, but numbers on both are to the right of the container.

**HTML**

```
<li class="team team-bottom">8. Salmonella/Onions   <span class="score">82</span> </li>
```

**CSS**

```
.score {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C7399;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  right: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}

.team {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: The code you have given us doesn't reproduce the problem you have described. Please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all the relevant code required to reproduce the problem, so that we can see what might be causing the it and be able to help.

Comment: Try providing some margin to the span element, might help. Your code is not very clear so I am not sure but maybe try once

Answer (score 0):

I had to assume some of your code. Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.score {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C7399;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  right: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}

.team {
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 50%;
}

ul {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="team team-bottom">8. Murder Hornets   <span class="score">82</span> </li>
<li class="team team-bottom">8. Salmonella/Onions   <span class="score">82</span> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `flex` and make it simple. You can use `justify-content:space-between OR space-around;` as per your requirement.

```css
.team {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #2C7399;
}
```

```html
<li class="team team-bottom">
  8. Salmonella/Onions
  <span class="score">82</span>
</li>
```